# How to find maximum outer time span and append?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to find for each ID, earliest measurement time before 00:00:00 and latest measurement time after 00:00:00. So that I can choose maximum overlapping start and ending time. Here is the sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,
                          2,2,2,
                          3,3,3],
    'timestamp': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 12:30:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00',
                  '2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 12:22:00', '2022-01-01 12:42:00',
                  '2022-01-01 12:45:00', '2022-01-01 12:55:00', '2022-01-01 13:05:00'],
    'VALUE1': [50, 80, 65,
               61,83,63,
               64,85,66],
    'gender': ['m', 'm', 'm',
               'f', 'f', 'f',
               'm', 'm', 'm',],
    'age': [7,7,7,
               8,8,8,
               6,6,6, ]
})
```

My expectation is to find T_start and T_end like (for a same day 24h measurement) in the picture. And then, append (like dashed lines) same value of last or first measurement. Please refer to the drawing since my wording of the problem might be confusing:[image]

What I have:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | 61 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |
| 3 | 64 | 2022-01-01 12:45:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | 85 | 2022-01-01 12:55:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | 66 | 2022-01-01 13:05:00 | m | 6 |

What I expect:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | ValueofPreviousEntry=65 | 2022-01-01 13:05:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | ValueofNextEntry=61 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 61 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | ValueofPreviousEntry | 2022-01-01 12:45:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | ValueofPreviousEntry | 2022-01-01 12:55:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | ValueofPreviousEntry | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | ValueofPreviousEntry | 2022-01-01 13:05:00 | f | 8 |
| 3 | ValueofNextEntry | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | ValueofNextEntry | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | ValueofNextEntry | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | ValueofNextEntry=64 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | 64 | 2022-01-01 12:45:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | 85 | 2022-01-01 12:55:00 | m | 6 |
| 3 | 66 | 2022-01-01 13:05:00 | m | 6 |

Comment: Hi, are you sure your example is coherent? For any given day, there is at least one ID that starts at 00:00:00 and one that ends at 23:40:00 (except on 2022-11-06, which ends at 23:00:00). Or is your question rather about filling values between T_start, T_end and each ID start and end time?

Comment: @Laurent my exyample might not be coherent and I am sorry for that. To articulate my problem, I draw the picture. I will attempt again to find a better sample data.

Comment: @Laurent I just changed the sample data and added tables about the expected output.

Comment: Your title Says "How to find maximum outer time span and append?". But I think you're actually trying to fill missing values (also called **data imputation**) only on outer missing values omitting inner missing values (some kind of padding), or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The following code uses only pandas functions without loops to solve the problem.

```py
# Prepare and reshape DataFrame
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df["gender"] = df.gender.replace({'f': 0, 'm': 1})
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'timestamp', columns = 'ID')

# Fill outer missing values
df = df.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1, group_keys = False
        ).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.first_valid_index():x.last_valid_index()]
                           .reindex(x.index, method = "nearest"))

# Bring back to original shape
df = df.stack(dropna = True).swaplevel(0, 1, axis = 0).sort_index()
df = df.replace({"gender": {0: 'f', 1: 'm'}}).convert_dtypes().reset_index()
```

This return the following DataFrame:

```py
>>> df

    ID           timestamp  VALUE1  age gender
0    1 2022-01-01 12:00:00      50    7      m
1    1 2022-01-01 12:30:00      80    7      m
2    1 2022-01-01 13:00:00      65    7      m
3    1 2022-01-01 13:05:00      65    7      m
4    2 2022-01-01 12:00:00      61    8      f
5    2 2022-01-01 12:02:00      61    8      f
6    2 2022-01-01 12:22:00      83    8      f
7    2 2022-01-01 12:42:00      63    8      f
8    2 2022-01-01 12:45:00      63    8      f
9    2 2022-01-01 12:55:00      63    8      f
10   2 2022-01-01 13:00:00      63    8      f
11   2 2022-01-01 13:05:00      63    8      f
12   3 2022-01-01 12:00:00      64    6      m
13   3 2022-01-01 12:02:00      64    6      m
14   3 2022-01-01 12:22:00      64    6      m
15   3 2022-01-01 12:30:00      64    6      m
16   3 2022-01-01 12:42:00      64    6      m
17   3 2022-01-01 12:45:00      64    6      m
18   3 2022-01-01 12:55:00      85    6      m
19   3 2022-01-01 13:05:00      66    6      m
```

The `df.groupby()` construct can be replaced by `df = df.ffill().bfill()`, if not only the outer missing values but all missing values should be filled with neighboring values.

---

In an older solution and in the long answer below instead of `df.groupby().apply()` there is a loop for the `df.groupby()` object:

```py
# Fill outer missing values & drop inner missing values
for gid, gdf in df.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1):
    tmin, tmax = gdf.dropna().index[[0, -1]] # get first & last index
    mask = gdf.index.map(lambda x: tmin <= x <= tmax and x not in gdf.dropna().index)
    df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, gid]] = gdf[~mask].ffill().bfill()
```

---

## Long Answer

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Convert timestamp to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# replace f/m with 0/1 (because pivot_table cannot aggregate type object)
df["gender"] = df.gender.replace({'f': 0, 'm': 1})

# Pivot table with timestamp as index
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'timestamp', columns = 'ID')
```

The DataFrame is pivoted and the columns are a MultiIndex (with "ID" as 2nd level):

```py
>>> print("Pivoted DataFrame:", df, sep = "\n")

Pivoted DataFrame:
                    VALUE1              age           gender          
ID                       1     2     3    1    2    3      1    2    3
timestamp                                                             
2022-01-01 12:00:00   50.0   NaN   NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN    1.0  NaN  NaN
2022-01-01 12:02:00    NaN  61.0   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN    NaN  0.0  NaN
2022-01-01 12:22:00    NaN  83.0   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN    NaN  0.0  NaN
2022-01-01 12:30:00   80.0   NaN   NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN    1.0  NaN  NaN
2022-01-01 12:42:00    NaN  63.0   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN    NaN  0.0  NaN
2022-01-01 12:45:00    NaN   NaN  64.0  NaN  NaN  6.0    NaN  NaN  1.0
2022-01-01 12:55:00    NaN   NaN  85.0  NaN  NaN  6.0    NaN  NaN  1.0
2022-01-01 13:00:00   65.0   NaN   NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN    1.0  NaN  NaN
2022-01-01 13:05:00    NaN   NaN  66.0  NaN  NaN  6.0    NaN  NaN  1.0
```

This would allow to easily [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) or [fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the missing values, if we would want to fill all missing value and not only the outer ones:

```py
df = df.ffill().bfill()
```

To only fill the missing values in the outer time span, we need a few more lines

```py
# Iterate over IDs (which are the 2nd level)
for gid, gdf in df.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1):
    # Get first and last non-NaN timestamp. Sort in case the index is not sorted.
    tmin, tmax = gdf.dropna().index.sort_values()[[0, -1]]
    # Creating a boolean mask which can be negated with "~"
    mask = gdf.index.map(lambda x: tmin <= x <= tmax and x not in gdf.VALUE1.dropna().index)
    # Fill missing values with the neighboring values & drop masked values
    df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, gid]] = gdf[~mask].ffill().bfill()
```

Now the only thing we need to do is to bring the DataFrame back to its original shape:

```py
df = df.stack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis = 0).sort_index(axis = 0).astype(int)
df = df.replace({"gender": {0: 'f', 1: 'm'}}).astype({"gender": "category"})
```

This gives us the final DataFrame with a MuliIndex, where the timestamp is the 2nd level:

```py
>>> print("MultiIndex DataFrame:", df, sep = "\n")

MultiIndex DataFrame:
                        VALUE1  age gender
ID timestamp                              
1  2022-01-01 12:00:00      50    7      m
   2022-01-01 12:30:00      80    7      m
   2022-01-01 13:00:00      65    7      m
   2022-01-01 13:05:00      65    7      m
2  2022-01-01 12:00:00      61    8      f
   2022-01-01 12:02:00      61    8      f
   2022-01-01 12:22:00      83    8      f
   2022-01-01 12:42:00      63    8      f
   2022-01-01 12:45:00      63    8      f
   2022-01-01 12:55:00      63    8      f
   2022-01-01 13:00:00      63    8      f
   2022-01-01 13:05:00      63    8      f
3  2022-01-01 12:00:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:02:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:22:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:30:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:42:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:45:00      64    6      m
   2022-01-01 12:55:00      85    6      m
   2022-01-01 13:05:00      66    6      m
```

To get rid of the MultiIndex, we can use `reset_index()`:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
```

To plot the data we can use either pandas builtin plot function or seaborn, which usually produces slightly better plots:

```py
# df.VALUE1.unstack().T.plot(marker = "o", linestyle = "-")
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = "timestamp", y = "VALUE1",
             hue = "ID", style = "gender", palette = "tab10")
```

[image: Plot of DataFrame]

Comment: I want to fill only the outer missing values. However, in the code, how can I keep new inner values without filling them? I think inner values are dropped because they are NaNs

Comment: So, do you want to keep the inner NaN values as they are? You can keep the NaN values if you pass `dropna = False` to `df.stack(dropna = False)`. Then you'll also have to discard `.astype(int)`, but you could append `.convert_dtypes()` in the next line instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```py
# Format values
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], infer_datetime_format=True)

# Iterate on timestamps to find missing ones for each subdataframes per age
dfs = []
for age in df["age"].unique():
    tmp = df.loc[df["age"] == age, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    min_timestamp = tmp["timestamp"].min()
    max_timestamp = tmp["timestamp"].max()
    for timestamp in df["timestamp"].unique():
        if (
            pd.Timestamp(timestamp) < min_timestamp
            or pd.Timestamp(timestamp) > max_timestamp
        ):
            tmp.loc[tmp.shape[0], :] = [pd.NA, timestamp, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]
    dfs.append(
        tmp.sort_values("timestamp").fillna(method="bfill").fillna(method="ffill")
    )

# Concatenate sub dataframes into one
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).astype({"VALUE1": int, "age": int})
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
     ID           timestamp  VALUE1 gender  age
0   1.0 2022-01-01 12:00:00      50      m    7
1   1.0 2022-01-01 12:30:00      80      m    7
2   1.0 2022-01-01 13:00:00      65      m    7
3   1.0 2022-01-01 13:05:00      65      m    7
4   2.0 2022-01-01 12:00:00      61      f    8
5   2.0 2022-01-01 12:02:00      61      f    8
6   2.0 2022-01-01 12:22:00      83      f    8
7   2.0 2022-01-01 12:42:00      63      f    8
8   2.0 2022-01-01 12:45:00      63      f    8
9   2.0 2022-01-01 12:55:00      63      f    8
10  2.0 2022-01-01 13:00:00      63      f    8
11  2.0 2022-01-01 13:05:00      63      f    8
12  3.0 2022-01-01 12:00:00      64      m    6
13  3.0 2022-01-01 12:02:00      64      m    6
14  3.0 2022-01-01 12:22:00      64      m    6
15  3.0 2022-01-01 12:30:00      64      m    6
16  3.0 2022-01-01 12:42:00      64      m    6
17  3.0 2022-01-01 12:45:00      64      m    6
18  3.0 2022-01-01 12:55:00      85      m    6
19  3.0 2022-01-01 13:05:00      66      m    6
```